# The radical of the commutator subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is the solvable radical of the commutator subgroup $G'$ of a group $G$ normal in $G$?

Comment: Informally, you can apply what Martin Isaacs calls the "the" test: if you can use the definite article "the", such as "**the** commutator subgroup of $G$" and "**the** solvable radical of $G'$", then the subgroup in question is characteristic. Specifically, the solvable radical of $G'$ is characteristic in $G'$, and $G'$ is characteristic in $G$. Since "characteristic" is a transitive property, i.e. $A \operatorname{char} B \operatorname{char} C$ implies $A \operatorname{char} C$, it follows that your solvable radical is in fact characteristic in $G$.

Comment: That's nice thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because the commutator subgroup is a characteristic subgroup of $G$. Then the claim follows from this duplicate:

[Prove that if $H$ is a characteristic subgroup of $K$, and $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849290/prove-that-if-h-is-a-characteristic-subgroup-of-k-and-k-is-a-normal-subgr)